# Vue JS does renders braces instead of result

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

Im using Vue JS (2.0.8) to render a list of devices. I have a health status that is represented by a number, so I use a method to convert the number to a CSS class to display it correctly. The problem is that Vue does not render the result of the method, but the method call itself.

**My Vue method:**

```
methods: {
    ...
    health: function (device) {
        if (device !== null) {
            switch (device.health.status) {
                case 2:
                    return "connected";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    return "warning";
                    break;
                case 0:
                    return "disconnected";
                    break;
                case -1:
                default:
                    return "unsupported";
                    break;
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

My HTML (Im using Laravel, hence the '@'):

```
<div v-for="device in devices" class="device">
    <div class="device-top">
        <div class="device-bullet @{{ health(device) }}"></div>
        <div v-on:click="device.open = !device.open" v-bind:class="{open: device.open}" class="device-more-info"><span class="icon icon-show-more"></span>More info</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This renders the following HTML:

```
<div class="device>
    <div class="device-top">
        <div class="device-bullet {{ health(device) }}"></div>
        <div class="device-more-info"><span class="icon icon-show-more"></span>More info</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this is the odd bit. If I move the @{{ health(device) to inside the device-bullet div instead of using it in an attribute, it renders like this (correctly, "connected" being the result of the function).

```
<div class="device>
    <div class="device-top">
        <div class="device-bullet">connected</div>
        <div class="device-more-info"><span class="icon icon-show-more"></span>More info</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried any combination I can think of to get it to render correctly but cannot seem to find the problem.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Interpolation within attributes is [removed](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Interpolation-within-Attributes-removed) in vuejs 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolation within attributes has been [removed in Vue 2.x](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Interpolation-within-Attributes-removed)

Use [v-bind:class](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax) instead:

```
<div class="device-bullet" v-bind:class="[health(device)]"></div>
```

Comment: +1, but you maybe you can consider adding [why](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Interpolation-within-Attributes-removed) for completeness.

Comment: @MathewJibin Thanks for the link. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of how laravel works, never used before.

But in "pure" vue can't use {{}} syntax to bind a html property. You need to use `v-bind` directive

```
<div v-bind:class="'device-bullet '+ health(device)" ></div>
```

Without `v-bind:` you're literally using `device-bullet {{ health(device) }}` as value.
For more clarification check [this docs section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Literal-vs-Dynamic)